# If intersection of finite closed set in normal space, show the following.

Tags: general-topology

Let the topological space $(X, \mathbf{T})$ be normal space, and $F_{1}, \cdots, F_{n}$ be closed sets in $X$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}=\varnothing$. Show that there exist open sets $U_{1}, \cdots, U_{n}$ such that $$F_{i} \subset U_{i}, \, \bar{U_1} \cap \cdots \cap \bar{U_{n}} = \varnothing$$

I tried to use mathematical induction, but it didn't work out. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve the problem or give me a hint.

Comment: Please [do not just ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): edit your post to present at least your attempt of proof by mathematical induction and where you were stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F = \bigcap_{i=2}^n F_i$ then $F\cap F_1 = \emptyset$, so because $X$ is normal we find $U_1$ open with $F\subset U_1$ such that $\overline{U_1}\cap F = \emptyset$. So we get a new set of closed sets $\{\overline{U_1},F_2,...,F_n\}$ with the same property as before. Repeat the same process for every $1\leq j\leq n$, with $\{\overline{U_i}\}_{i\leq j} \cup\{F_i\}_{i\geq j}$, the result is your solution.